# Why does processing try-catch without any exception thrown not slow down the program at all?

Tags: java, try-catch

Today I realized something that appeared weird to me: I noticed that when I just do

```
try {
    doSomething();
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

it isn't slower at all than if I just do

```
doSomething();
```

So I ran a test and wrote down some quick code to prove what I saw, the code basically just loops over a function called doSomething() lots of times, one time without and one time with try-catch surrounding it. So here's the code to it if you want to test it yourself:

```
public class Main {

private static final long LOOPS = 1000000L;

public static final void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Loop without try catch: "+loopWithoutTryCatch(LOOPS));
    System.out.println("Loop with try catch: "+loopWithTryCatch(LOOPS));
}

public static long loopWithoutTryCatch(long loops)
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (long i = 0L; i < loops; i++)
    {
        doSomething();
    }

    return System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
}

public static long loopWithTryCatch(long loops)
{
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    for (long i = 0L; i < loops; i++)
    {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    return System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime;
}

public static void doSomething()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
    {
        if (i % 3 == 0)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
}
```

And I received the following output:

```
Loop without try catch: 375
Loop with try catch: 373
```

I was surprised so I tested it again and again, but I always got similar results, both ways it runs pretty much in the same time.

And now my question is: Why?

I dont really understand it, as far as I know try-catch writes the resources before usage in some kind of table to later - if any exception is thrown - be able to clean it up and reference to the values it had before the exception occured.

This should take at least some time, shouldn't it? 
I thought it is maybe because I the random example I choose doesnt represent it properly, and in that specific case in which I tested it it doesnt slow down anything, but that seemed very unlikely to me.

Then I thought maybe it just takes such a tiny amount of time that it isnt noticable with that "few" amount of executions, so I ran the test program again with a total number of 10 million loopings, but what I found just prooved what I had already found: It takes pretty much the same time for both executions.

So is there any logical explanation for that this is the case or just a example-specific behaviour of try-catch?

Thanks for any clarification in advance.

Comment: creating exception with all stack information is the costlier part. If you are not creating and throwing it, the overhead is that big. You may change the tests to create and throw to see impact.

Comment: just in case:  you may find http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ useful for micro bench marking

Comment: @reechard Even in proper English (that would be British, the original English) it's program, not programme. Programme is for a TV show.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "slowness" in `throw` / `catch` blocks comes from the process of throwing and catching the exception, not in the process of setting up "traps" for them. When you throw an exception, JVM must

- Create an instance of an exception
- Prepare space for the stack trace
- Populate the stack trace into the prepared space
- "Unwind" the stack down to the correct place
- Pass the control to your exception handler.

When none of that is happening, JVM simply sticks a note that an exception handler is available at this level on the stack, and continues executing the actual code.

Making the feature penalty-free was a very important goal for language designers: programmers should not be required to pay for things that they do not use. Otherwise, programmers would be tempted to skip exception handling or go back to the C ways of using status codes in order to save a few CPU cycles here and there, spelling the end to the exceptions as a feature.

Answer (score 6):

The bytecode generated from code like yours follows this pattern

```
 1: invoke method
 2: goto 4
 3: store exception in catch block variable
   // would contain handling code if there was any
 4: return // or whatever comes after the try-catch

Exception table
   if an exception of the type in catch block happens from 1 to 3, goto 3
```

So basically all you have added with a `try-catch` is an extra goto if no exceptions occur. Otherwise, the JVM will lookup the exception in the exception table and match where it occurred. It will then prepare the `Exception` and goto whatever instruction index is specified. *That whole operation is heavy.*

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev If you have the compiled `.class` files, you can check bytecode in human readable form with the `javap` application.